# How to retrieve a particular row from the dataframe and assign the values retrieved to the input controls in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a Shiny app and when the Email ID is selected from the **selectizeInput()** then I want to retrieve the data from data frame according to the user's selection and fill the fetched values to the input controls. For Instance, if the Email ID (say abc.xyz@xmail.com) is selected by user then it should fill the first name as abc, last name as xyz in the application designed where first name and last name are the columns present in the data frame.
The code used is :

```
observeEvent(input$email,{
      check <-  paste(input$email)
    fetchvalue <- sqldf("select * from PeopleViewer where `Email` == 'check'")
    input$`first name` <- fetchvalue$`first name`
             })
```

But this code does not work properly.. Can anyone help to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot assign something like this to shiny input `input$first.name <- something`. Your question says that you want to "fill the fetched values to the input controls", what kind of "input controls"? What do you wish to do with the first name and last name?

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the `update*` functions? For each type of input widget there is a corresponding update function. You can use these to programmatically set the value of input widgets.

For example, if `first_name` was a `textInput` widget then the command to set the widget text to "hello world" is:

```
updateTextInput(session, "first_name", value = "hello world")
```

You want something of this nature in your observer function.

Comment: I tried using **UpdateTextInput()**. But it didn't get updated. The code used is:                                  `observeEvent(input$email,{
  check <-  paste(input$email)
  fetchvalue <- sqldf("select * from PeopleViewer where `Email` == 'check'")
  updateTextInput(session, "fn",value = fetchvalue$`First Name`)
})`

Comment: First check that the observe event is triggering when expected. I usually do this by adding a print statement inside observe event. This makes it print to the console when the observer runs.

Comment: Second, check the format of `fetchvalue$First_Name` if this is not of type character then it will not work to update the textInput with it. One way to check is again to add a print statement inside the observe - get it to print the value you will update with. You might have to call `as.character(fetchvalue$First_Name)` or something similar.